# Cannot play mp3 stream with JMF

Tags: java, servlets, jmf

I have some short audio player example code like this that runs fine:

```
public class AudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Format input1 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEGLAYER3);
        Format input2 = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.MPEG);
        Format output = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.LINEAR);
        PlugInManager.addPlugIn(
                "com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.JavaDecoder",
                new Format[]{input1, input2},
                new Format[]{output},
                PlugInManager.CODEC);
        try {
            Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new File("tone.mp3").toURL());
            player.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now i wanted to stream the mp3 from a servlet with:

```
Manager.createPlayer(new URL("http://localhost:88/media/tone.mp3"));
```

The servlet receives the request i open a test file and send to the requester. The problem is the mp3 is not played (no sound) and no error message at all.

If i download the file via browser the file plays correct.

The servlet goes like this:

```
public class MediaSource extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.err.println(req);

        File mp3 = new File("tone.mp3");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(mp3);

        resp.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
        resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + mp3.getName());

        resp.setContentLength((int) mp3.length());

        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int n = in.read(buf, 0, 1024);
        while (n > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
            out.flush();
            n = in.read(buf, 0, 1024);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**Update** for @jogabonito

That are the events

```
javax.media.TransitionEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,previous=Unrealized,current=Realizing,target=Started]
javax.media.CachingControlEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,cachingControl=com.sun.media.protocol.DataSource$CachingControl@f9f9d8,progress=102400]
javax.media.DurationUpdateEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,duration=javax.media.Time@1decdec
javax.media.RealizeCompleteEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,previous=Realizing,current=Realized,target=Started]
javax.media.TransitionEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,previous=Realized,current=Prefetching,target=Started]
javax.media.CachingControlEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,cachingControl=com.sun.media.protocol.DataSource$CachingControl@f9f9d8,progress=204800]
javax.media.CachingControlEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,cachingControl=com.sun.media.protocol.DataSource$CachingControl@f9f9d8,progress=205889]
javax.media.PrefetchCompleteEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,previous=Prefetching,current=Prefetched,target=Started]
javax.media.StartEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,previous=Prefetched,current=Started,target=Started,mediaTime=javax.media.Time@691f36,timeBaseTime=javax.media.Time@18020cc]
javax.media.EndOfMediaEvent[source=com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler@c2ea3f,previous=Started,current=Prefetched,target=Prefetched,mediaTime=javax.media.Time@e94e92]
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you implement the ControllerListener interface and then check for ControllerEvents. We can then find out which stage of player creation is failing

Comment: From the log, all seems normal. One more question, when you play file from local storage, as in Player player = Manager.createPlayer(new File("tone.mp3").toURL());  Is the player object which is being created com.sun.media.content.unknown.Handler ?    I would have thought that it would be  com.sun.media.content.audio.mp3.Handler

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The JMF code looks solid, and servlets arent really my thing :-) Maybe someone else could help.